# Is it possible to fit 8.2 million of triangles in a VR scene for a standalone HMD?

Tags: performance, unity-game-engine, gis, virtual-reality

I'm making a VR application where a 3D map is displayed. I'm using Unity 2021.3.22 and XR Interaction Toolkit. I've been able to represent buildings by using GIS data. The problem is that the number of triangles increases from 842 k to 8.2 M, so my Meta/Oculus Quest 2 isn't able to easily move the scene. I already merged the building polyhedrons in Blender by 1 meter to reduce the number of vertices. Now I'm able to handle the scene in PC-VR, but I want to target the standalone version of this device. Do you have any idea to make the scene lighter without sacrificing the buildings in the scene or merging them even more? By the way, I can't simplify building messes since they are already simple polyhedrons.